# PySpark: Cleaning hundreds of string columns for a 1mb parquet file is absurdly slow

Tags: pyspark

What can I do to speedup these trivial string cleaning operations aside from cacheing (already implemented)? In Pandas, this would take seconds:

```
    # load version
    df = spark.sql(f"select DISTINCT * from {table}").cache()
    
    # get dtypes
    string_cols = [col for col, dtype in df.dtypes if dtype == 'string']
    numeric_cols = [col for col, dtype in df.dtypes if dtype not in ['string', 'date', 'timestamp', 'boolean']]

    # clean strings; replace null with missing value
    df = df.na.fill(value='<missing>', subset=[f"`{col}`" for col in string_cols])
    # clean numeric; replace null with missing value
    df = df.na.fill(value=-9999, subset=[f"`{col}`" for col in numeric_cols])
    
    # string specific
    for col in string_cols:
        df = df.withColumn(f"{col}", trim(df[f"`{col}`"]))
        df = df.withColumn(f"{col}", when(df[f"`{col}`"] == '', '<missing>').otherwise(df[f"`{col}`"]))
```

Comment: This is not really a single specific question, but an entire area / practice.   Read [https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-performance-tuning/] and try to follow the suggestions there.

Comment: Sample input, sample output?